# Returning focus on blur with inputs, which have same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on one page many inputs, which have same class and dont have ID.
Attached to bind event of class selector, for returning focus if condition is true.

But when click in another input- focus not return.
 
Think then 'cause in another element work blur, but dont know how need solve this.

```
<input class="test" value="">
<input class="test" value="">

$(document).ready(function(){
      if (condition) {
    // return focus - not work
    $(".test").blur(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).focus();
        }, 100);
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

First, once the `setTimeout` function executes `this` is now the `window` object instead of one of the inputs. Store the reference to the original `this` as part of the blur handler.

Second, the condition check should be moved. As it sits now, you will effectively be forced to never leave an input box once you blur it because the blur handler has been attached and *always* re-focuses. I don't know what your `condition` is so I am going to place it in the `setTimeout` callback. It could also go before the `setTimeout` creation.

**[Here's a verbose demo fiddle of an assumed implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/JQ76U/3/)**. Below is a watered down example:

```
<input class="test" value="">
<input class="test" value="">

$(document).ready(function(){
    // return focus - not work
    $(".test").blur(function(){
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (condition) {
            $(that).focus();
          }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: You may see you variant http://jsfiddle.net/JQ76U/   Not correctly work- blur work and on another input.

Comment: `condition` plays a vital role in what is considered "correct". I have a dummy demo at http://jsfiddle.net/JQ76U/3/. I'll update my answer with some explanation

Comment: Yes, problem not in condition. but sorry, you example non-correctly work. Run demo- set cursor in 1 input. Click in 2 input- focus not returned in 1 input.  Same and run demo- curor in 2 input, after click in 1 input- focus not returned :(

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be *in* blur event, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UudLV/1/

It returns focus to the last focused input if the inputs value is empty.

```
$(".test").blur(function() {
    if($(this).val().length === 0) { //Your condition, can be anything
        $(this).focus(); //Return focus
    }
});
```

Return the focus to the last focused element has nothing to do with the selector. The `on blur` event passes the last focused element to the callback function as context, therefore, `this` will be the element.

Edit*
I'm not entirely sure this is what OP wants to do.